# Newly created view not visible in ClearCase explorer: how can I see it?

Tags: clearcase

I created a view using the ClearCase explorer.

But after its creation, the view is not visible in the listing of views within the explorer.
I tried closing the explorer and starting again. But no use...
What would you suggest?

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend the following procedure:

- open a DOS windows
- goes to the root of your view ( `c:\path\to\myView` for snapshot views, `M:\MyView` for dynamic view)
- type '`clearexplorer .` (note the 'space-dot' after the `clearexplorer` command)

That should:

- open your ClearCase explorer directly on the right view
- add the right view shortcut

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes ALBD service of the ClearCase doesnot start due to which you will not be able to view the clearcase views.

To solve this problem,

Go to control panel for windows machine and restart the clearcase services in ClearCase properties and try and check.

The views will be shown now.

Answer (score 0):

my issue was resolved with going to the menu of ClearCase Explorer:

View > Refresh View Shortcuts (shortcut is ALT+F5)

Answer (score 0):

None of the below seemed to work, I tried them all, they all seemed reasonable.  I could see the new views and the associated drive letters in Windows Explorer but ClearCase Explorer DID NOT see the new view.  So what I had to do was go to the ClearCase Explorer Views tab, right click and 'Add View Shortcut'. Select the correct View Type (Snapshot or Dynamic) and then select the correct View Tag and press OK.  I did not need to select the correct page, it made a new one for the "new" view and it filled in the Drive Letter.

I had deleted a view thru ClearCase Explorer and tried to resurrect it which may of led me to this predicament.